# "set" directive is not allowed here

Tags: variables, nginx, configuration

I am trying to follow this example here- https://gist.github.com/morhekil/1ff0e902ed4de2adcb7a#file-nginx-conf but getting error-  `"set" directive is not allowed here`

what am I doing wrong? Note that I am using openresty and invoking nginx as-

```
nginx -p `pwd`/ -c conf/nginx.conf
```

The context of my nginx.conf matches exactly as https://gist.github.com/morhekil/1ff0e902ed4de2adcb7a#file-nginx-conf

If I move the set variable to server section, I no longer get that error but a new error-

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown "resp_body" variable
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

After months, an answer is coming :)

Github configuration file seems wrong. `set` directive is used in `server`, `location` and `if` blocks.

Syntax: set $variable value;
Default:    — 
Context:    **server, location, if**

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#set

Good luck!

Comment: That being said... using "set" in if-blocks is not recommended as it can have side-effects. Article about it here "If is Evil" https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/ . I'm trying to wrap my head around how this guy's snippet even works: https://github.com/czerasz/nginx-configuration-examples/blob/develop/config/maintenance-page.conf#L1 . Notice that on line #1? How is that code even running, the config would fail! Wonder if an older version of `nginx` could run `set` at the top-level context.

Answer (score 3):

I required a variable to set once [globally] and its value be accessible throughout every server block. The map directive worked for my situation, such as:

```
map $host $path_to_trunk {
  default "/Users/ruter/Sites/example.co/trunk";
}
```

With above `map` block, I had access to `$path_to_trunk` in every server block, such as:

```
server {
    server_name www.example.local;
    root ${path_to_trunk}/www;
}

server {
    server_name cdn.example.local;
    root ${path_to_trunk}/www/images/content;
}
```